# Unable to use Edge Split to split the UV Shpere

Tags: edges

I only started using Blender 2.93 a few months ago and it can be very frustrating at times.

For instance, I am trying to split a UV sphere into a few parts, as I following along with this [hair tutorial around 6:07](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spikKMGAgDA&t=40s)

I use Select> Select loops> Edge Loops to select the portion that I would like to separate from the original object.

As you can see by my screenshot, [image: my screenshot] that when I right click to select Edge Split, then the sphere does NOT split into a separate portion. It still displays as just one Sphere.

As usual, thanks in advance

EDIT: I am adding another screenshot showing the result of selecting Edge split in the video[image: screenshot of the video]

Adding blend file:
[image]

Comment: what happens if you select one of these vertices and move it?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? You won't see anything happen until you actually select the separated parts as she shows later in the video. [Upload](https://blend-exchange.com/help) your blend file so that we can see what's happening:

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the video. After she clicks on Edge Split, you can see that it creates a new sphere - Sphere04 - but when I click on Edge Split, I still only have one sphere

Comment: @JohnEason - I have added the blend file

Comment: @moonboots - if I select a vertice and use the G to move, then it moves but not the entire section. BTW, since I have selected Edge Split, the front portion no longer selects (Edge loops) the front section that I was trying to make. It is as if Blender split those loops from each other

Comment: it works fine here, if you select an edge and Split Faces by Edges it will rip the edge, if you do it on the opposite side, then it will create 2 parts as if you cut with a knife, press L to select a part

Comment: is it what you're trying to do? https://zupimages.net/up/21/46/5jml.gif

Comment: Go into face mode (3) instead of vertex mode, select one of the faces then hover the mouse over the section and hit 'L'. That will select the whole section that you've just cut out and you can move it with 'G'. If you have 'Random' colour selected under the viewport shading options (dropdown at R/H end of the 3D window header) you'll see that each section is now a different colour as in the video.

Comment: @moonboots this is interesting, take a UV sphere and edge split only one side of it and you'll find that it's hard to alt+click to select one of the split edge groups, I think it has something to do with the top and bottom vert of a UV sphere being shared on so many faces, perhaps

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions, but it was not working for me, until I switched to Face Select and selected each "tile" separately, followed by Mesh> Separate> Selection. Now I have a Sphere.001 shape underneath the original Sphere. When I use the G tool, I can move the entire new mesh. I do not believe that I can answer my question yet, but when I can, then I will add the new screenshot to show that it was accomplished

Comment: @ Allen Simpson, actually what you say is true for any edge that is part of a grid, no?